# Is there a way to find if a python object has an attribute?

Tags: python

I'm trying to verify if a python object has an attribute inside the definition of one of its  methods, here is some code to clarify :

```py
class A :
    def __init__(self) : 
        self.__a = 5
    def hasAttr(self) : 
        if hasattr(self, '__a'):
            print(True)
        else : 
            print(False)
```

If I execute the code

```
x = A()
x.hasAttr()
```

I get `False`, I know the reason it doesn't work is that the attribute is virtually private, but I'm not intending to access the attributes outside of the class, I just want to verify if the attribute has been yet definded , I know I can always use :

```py
class A :
    def __init__(self) : 
        self.__a = 5
    def hasAttr(self) : 
        if ('_'+self.__class__.__name__ + '__a') in self.__dict__:
            print(True)
        else : 
            print(False)
```

But isn't there a more soft way to do it ?

Comment: `hasattr` works in this way: `if hasattr(self, '_'+self.__class__.__name__ + '__a'):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double underscore variables are [name mangled](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) adding the class name in front of the method, so `__a` becomes `_A__a` as you rightly identified, hence you get `False` in the first case.

Similarly you can do `hasattr(self, '_'+self.__class__.__name__ + '__a')` in the second case

```
class A :

    def __init__(self) :
        self.__a = 5

    def hasAttr(self) :

        attr_name = f'_{self.__class__.__name__}__a'
        if hasattr(self, attr_name):
            print(True)
        else :
            print(False)

x = A()
x.hasAttr()
```

Or you can use EAFP approach to try to access the variable, and print True or False accordingly

```
class A :

    def __init__(self) :
        self.__a = 5

    def hasAttr(self):

        attr_name = f'_{self.__class__.__name__}__a'
        try:
            getattr(self, attr_name)
            print(True)
        except:
            print(False)

x = A()
x.hasAttr()
```

The output will be `True`

Comment: yeah I agree, it's just that I thought maybe there is a better way to so, that I don't know of yet.

Comment: Well the dunder variable is always name mangled, if you want a better approach, perhaps not defining it a dunder variable is a good idea @AyoubZAROU

Comment: I guess I  will stick with the approach you just gave on your solution , thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AttributeError` exception to test if you have an attribute:

```
class A :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.__a = 5
    def hasAttr(self):
        try:
            self.__a
            return True
        except AttributeError:
            return False

x = A()
print(x.hasAttr())
```

Prints:

```
True
```